# How to keep access token

Tags: php, facebook-authentication

I'd like to make simple fb app, but I cant find how access token shoud be kept.
I mean that when user login i got 60days access token and its cool, but what if user changes password? What is the better way to valid access token, and get new one ?

Comment: The best way is to wait till your user comes back so you can refresh the token. This is exactly what the token is there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has a post on their blog that may help you called `How-To: Handle expired access tokens`

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

Comment: thanks a lot, its good solution, but fb docs are a lil bit unclear, they post some tips on blog instead of create normal documentation. What are these vars $my_url, and $_REQUEST['CODE'],for what are they responsible.

Comment: Lol. Yes, I agree that Facebook needs to work on that. Also, I'm a little confused by your question about the vars, can you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, English is not my native language. So what url should be in $my_url, and what is stored in $_REQUEST['CODE'], also they say " // known valid access token stored in a database 
  $access_token = "YOUR_STORED_ACCESS_TOKEN";" so, have I to save every user access token in my external db ?

Comment: $my_url is the URL of your app that will be doing the auth and the $_REQUEST['code'] is auth code that is either being POST'ed or GET'ed... not sure how to properly say GET'ed

Comment: Thanks for fast replies ;)  so if I get auth code, it means that access token is active ? And do I have to save access token in my external db ?

Comment: Yes you can store that in your DB. If there is an access token in the DB, it could be expired. However if you get a NEW access token from FB it is a valid token otherwise FB would send you an error message and not a token.